# (Kubuntu) No steam games will start

Tags: kubuntu, games, steam

I'm new to Linux systems so this might be really easy to fix. but recently i have been re installing all of my games. the first two that were installed (Hacknet, and Axiom Verge) worked perfectly fine then i installed skyrim through play-on Linux and the windows version of steam but not when i go back to the Linux version of steam i cant play any of the games. i will post the error logs if some one tells me how to get them (again i'm brand new to Linux).

and yes i have already tried re-starting my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Only games, which a running on linux will work, not all Steam games. So, you're first place to drop-in would be the app-database of Wine,

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24749

Can you start steam? If not, than you might not even have installed wine.

Comment: the games i have installed are for steam there being installed through the linux steam launcher its just after i installed skyrim with playonlinux and wine all the games on the linux steam stopped working

Comment: I'm no expert at this, but if you don't find another solution I would check: a) if deleting Skyrim helps, b) if not then if installing Skyrim is really the cause of the problem (by reinstalling steam and 1 broken game and skyrim) and c) ask at Skyrim support or related (Playonlinux maybe?)